# Does Lion drain mana when my mana is full?

Tags: dota-2

Suppose that I am playing Lion, and my mana is currently full.  If I use my Mana Drain ability on an enemy hero, will it actually drain any mana from him/her/it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**.  Lion's mana drain will continue to drain mana from the target even if Lion is at full mana.

[I made a gif of it.](http://gfycat.com/HardtofindSpeedyGuineapig)